# Center image in view

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I'm trying to center an image on the screen. I thought it would be as simple as my code example, but it just seem to add space in the bottom. Any ideas how to make it centered?

```
if (imageView.frame.size.height > imageView.frame.size.width){
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = scrollView.frame.size.height / imageView.frame.size.height
        margin = ((scrollView.frame.size.height - imageView.frame.size.height) / 2.0)
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(margin, 0, margin, 0)

    }
```

Comment: Is `imageView` placed in `scrollView`? Do you use autolayout?

Comment: The answer is yes on both questions @mixel

Comment: I can not understand why are you using  `UIScrollView` here. Is it not easier  to just center `imageView` in view where  `scrollView` placed?

Comment: I'm sure you are right, but I'm very new to Swift so nothing really makes sense to me yet. How do I do what you are suggesting? @mixel

Comment: It's not about Swift but about autolayout. You should add zero left and right constraints to `imageView` parent and then add `Vertically in Container` constraint. You better should read some tutorials on autolayout.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its simple... make use of the strengths of auto layout and set the constraints. This is what I did.

[image]